# How to remove 3 months from a date column in DAX

Tags: sorting, date, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I was wondering if you can help with below

I need to write have a conditional column for 3 month prior to review date

So, I have "review dates" column which contains review dates, and  need something along the lines of "IF 3 months left before "Review Date" them then ALERT, otherwise NO ALERT"

Ideally to have rolling code so I don't have to alter it manually every time dates change

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Not sure how to approach

Comment: Please include sample code/sample data with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeap, I guess you can! but compare against what ? Today's date? If It is so, then Please create a new calculated column, and try this code! let me know If It is what you are looking for!

```
    Logical_Result =
VAR NowIsTheTime =
    NOW ()
RETURN
    IF (
        DATEDIFF ( YourTable[ReviewDate], NowIsTheTime, MONTH ) < 3,
        "ALERT",
        "NO ALERT"
    )
```

If we test it on a table as column, It gives us:

[image: Final Image]

Comment: Hi Ozan, seems OP means, that he has some deadline called `Review date` and he want to know if `Reiew date >(today +3 Months)`

Comment: Hello Mik! Thanks! Yes, Logical! 

Comment: and the measure counts before now(), I mean that `<3` should be replaced with `>-3` in the measure